# Python 3: User input random numbers to see if multiples of 5. Then get the sum of all the numbers that were multiples of 5

Tags: python

I spent all day on this code. It failed.

```
def output (n):
  n = int(input('Enter a number: ')

while n != 0:
    if n % 5 == 0:
      print(n, 'Yes')
    n = int(input('Enter a number: ')
    if n == 0
      output = range(1, int(input('Enter a number: '))+1)
      print (output)
output (n)
```

Question is:

1. let user enter integers to determine if multiple of 5.
2. If it is then keep count that will keep a sum of all numbers that are multiples of 5.
3. Task done using a loop in a function and the loop will terminate when a value of 0 is entered.
4. when the loop terminates, return the count of how many numbers that were multiple of 5s.

After complete, NEXT:
pass the variable sum_multiple_five to another function called print_result() and still
print the same message but now the print will be done in its own function.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly is failing? Please indicate how it is failing

Comment: Why do you have both a function and variable called output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ has mentioned the key point, when you call your variable output you overwrite the function. So when you try to call the function at the end you are actually "calling" the variable

Comment: It seems very odd to have a function named `output()` that actually takes _input_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def sum_multiple_five(n):
  count = 0 
  if n == 0: #initial check if the first input is 0 if it is return count as 0 
    return count
  while n != 0: # not leaving this while loop until n is 0
    if n % 5 == 0: #if divisible by 5 increment count by 1 otherwise get new input
      count = count + 1
    n = int(input('Enter a number: ')) # Update n's value from user input. This is important because n is what the while loop is checking.

  return count #when the while loop exit as user input 0 we return count 

def print_result(answer):
  # print(answer)
  print( str(answer) + " numbers were multiple of 5s")


def init():
  n = int(input('Enter a number: ')) #get user input and store it in variable n
  print_result(sum_multiple_five(n)) #call sum_multiple_five() function and use n as an input. then give the returned int to print_result function


init() #call the function init()
```

result:

```
Enter a number:  10
Enter a number:  10
Enter a number:  100
Enter a number:  50
Enter a number:  5
Enter a number:  9
Enter a number:  7
Enter a number:  10
Enter a number:  4
Enter a number:  15
Enter a number:  5
Enter a number:  8
Enter a number:  2
Enter a number:  0
8 numbers were multiple of 5s
```

Comment: it is giving you the count

Comment: Excellent! You rock. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than attempt to illustrate the topic or provide any valuable comment, all you do is blindly provide an answer to the original question.

Comment: Agreed. However, I do see where I made an error and am able to understand the code. I want to thank everyone for their work and have up-voted everyone.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks everyone. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(n):
    if not n%5:
        print (n,'Yes')
        return n
    else:
        print (n,'No')
        return 0

total = 0
while True:
    n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if not n:
        break
    total+=test(n)

print(total)
```